# При обновлении страницы событие не отрабатывает до конца

Tags: javascript, html, css, события

Есть блок `div` у которого по умолчанию задано свойство `display:none;` При определенном событии блок появляется исходя из условий `if-else`, но если пользователь обновит страницу - блок пропадает, хоть событие остается по-прежнему актуальным и незавершенным. Как этот момент обыграть?

Comment: Без кода события ничем помочь нельзя. А лучше дополнительно сделать минимальный работающий пример на [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: @lolbas однако необходимость наличия кода в самом вопросе fiddle не отменяет.

Comment: По поводу вопроса: либо хранить данные о событии на сервере и передавать их на страницу, либо хранить в браузере в `localStorage`, но это не столь долговечно.

Comment: @lolbas вот тут минимальный пример[http://jsfiddle.net/ligisayan/4nndjojj/2/] После удаления remove_item страница перезагружается или сам пользователь обновляет и блок с классом `fixed-bottom` уже не отображается, хотя в  `.fixed-bottom .cart_list li` нет класса `empty`

Comment: фишка в том, что переход по ссылке с классом `.remove-item` происходит раньше, чем обрабатывается обработчик события, т.е. условие не выполняется при перезагрузке потому, что на старой странице клик не успел обработаться, а на новой еще никто не кликнул

Comment: @Regent а подскажите как это `хранить в браузере в localStorage` ?

Comment: По поводу самого `localStorage`: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage, http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Comment: По поводу _что хранить_: флаг-статус, или число-статус, или селектор элемента - что хотите и что вам нужно для достижения результата.

Comment: @Regent так как я написал в ответе ниже?

Comment: В общем и целом - да. У `<div>` нет `.value` - есть только `.textContent` и `.innerHTML`. А идея с хранилищем верная.

Comment: @Regent т.е. div не сохранится с содержимым таким образом?

Comment: Замените `.value` на `.textContent` (если нужно сохранить только текст элемента) или на `.innerHTML` (если нужно сохранить HTML-структуру  внутри элемента).

Answer (score 1):

```js
var field = document.getElementById("fix-bot");
console.log(field);

// Проверяем, что значение поля autosave существует
// (это будет происходить при случайной перезагрузке страницы)
if (sessionStorage.getItem("autosave")) {
  // Восстановить значение тестового поля
  field.innerHTML = sessionStorage.getItem("autosave");
  console.log("autosave");
}

// Прослушивать изменения значения текстового поля
field.addEventListener("change", function() {
  // И сохранить результаты в объект хранилища сессий
  sessionStorage.setItem("autosave", field.innerHTML);
  console.log("change");
});
```

```html
<div id="fix-bot">
  <!-- содержимое блока -->
</div>
```

Comment: @Regent подправил как вы мне подсказали. через консоль вижу, что в field записывается все правильно, и скорее всего сохраняет результат в хранилище тоже правильно - выводит в виде `div#fix-bot.fixed-bottom` и кучей параметров, а вот с восстановлением пока не ясно или может быть влияет то, что блок по умолчанию скрыт, а появляется при заданных условиях? и еще пишет, что "object state below is captured upon first expansion"

Comment: @Regent а извлекать параметры из `localStorage` в селектор как-то можно?